# DevDay 2015 - Duas Vagas na Casa!

Tags: debate

Moçada,

Aluguei uma casa com espaço para até 5 pessoas em Belo Horizonte, dias 30 e 31 de Outubro, pelo Airbnb. Há ainda espaço para mais duas pessoas.

Estamos dividindo o custo da casa entre 3 pessoas. Com mais duas pessoas, conseguimos abaixar o custo total (média de 110 reais por dia, entre três). Quem se interessar se manifeste aqui por resposta.